# Что я добавляю в список: объекты или ссылки?

Tags: java, ооп, объекты, списки

Нужно создать объекты, сделать список и перебрать в цикле. Можно ли делать так:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();

ArrayList objList = new ArrayList();
objList.add(obj);
objList.add(obj2);

for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {
    //Делаем работу
}
```

Или так:

```
ArrayList objList = new ArrayList();

objList.add(new MyClass());
objList.add(new MyClass());

for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {
    //Делаем работу
}
```

Можно ли так делать? Что добавляется в список в первом случае: новые объекты или ссылка на уже созданные объекты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `new` в Java возвращает ссылку на созданный объект. Рассмотрим, что же происходит в обеих случаях.

1. Переменной `obj` типа `MyClass` вы присваиваете ссылку на объект типа `MyClass`.

`MyClass obj = new MyClass();`

Сам объект создается в динамической памяти, а оператор `new` возвращает ссылку на эту память. Так что, даже когда Вы используете переменную `obj`, Вы манипулируете ссылкой на объект! И теперь, думаю ясно что этой строкой кода:

`objList.add(obj);`

**Вы добавляете ссылку на объект, а не сам объект!** Теперь программа имеет 2 ссылки на объект: `obj` и `objList`.

2. Как я уже говорил, оператор `new` возвращает ссылку на созданный объект. Поэтому можно написать так:

`objList.add(new MyClass());`

В данном случае, созданный объект будет иметь одну ссылку и получить его можно будет так (допустим это первый элемент в `objList`):

`objList.get(0);`

### В чем разница?

Если Вы планируете в дальнейшем использовать созданный объект - используйте первый вариант. Наоборот, если Вы уверены, что ссылка на объект Вам не к чему - используйте второй способ.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли так делать?

Можно. Оба варианта эквиваленты.

> Что добавляется в список в первом случае: новые объекты или ссылка на уже созданные объекты?

Ссылка на уже созданные объекты.